# Converting OBJ to IGES

Tags: unity-game-engine, 3d, file-conversion

Can I convert an OBJ to IGES?
I understand that OBJ has nothing but a point cloud and IGES has surfaces.
Is there a way to toggle between the two formats?

Comment: I tried FreeCAD but it takes a lot of time to process and finally fails without converting the obj to an IGES

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are ways to convert from OBJ to IGES, however you might not get the results you expected. If you try important an OBJ and then converting into an IGES file in FreeCAD, you will need to make sure that you have a low poly count and if not, reduce the number of vertices, because FreeCAD will try converting every one of those points into a surface, which will blow up the file size and result in an unusable mess.

Comment: What other options do I have other than free cad

Comment: @Praveen  try meshlab.

Comment: Do you think meshlab can do it? I dont think so

Answer (score 1):

You can download FreeCAD and import a obj file and export to an iges file. Hope this helped!

Comment: Anything other than FreeCAD?

Comment: Can a STL file be imported into any CAD software?